# No Mobile Network In Samsung Grand Prime

Tags: samsung, mobile-network

Samsung Grand Prime Phone. There is no Mobile Network. I tried `*#*#4636#*#*` but it didn't bring up the Testing Menu. I am not able to search operator or change the network mode. The IMEI in `*#06#` and in the phone is same.

When I remove the sim it displays insert sim card. When I reinsert it, it's able to find there is a sim inserted but there is no signal.

I installed [Network Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ather.networkmode) app and it shows Radio is Off. Turn Radio On is not working.

When I get into settings for mobile network, it will not allow me to search. When I click search it will say mobile network not available. Both automatic and manual search says the same. The SIM works fine in another device. I can confirm its definitely device.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

I have updated the phone using Kies and now its in 5.0.2. Still no signal. There is a Blocked Symbol near the Wifi Symbol

[image: Blocked Symbol Near Wifi] [image: Network Cell Info] [image: BaseBand] [image: Status]

**EDIT2**
How to check that I have correct modem for the phone ?

Comment: Does it show a proper string in Settings - Baseband version? Also, in more extreme cases, is the phone compatible with your carrier (e.g. don't run a CDMA card in a GSM-only phone)?

Comment: Yes it shows proper baseband in settings.  Its an GSM phone and I am trying GSM sim only. I am not able to call Emergency Number too. It says Radio Off

Comment: That testing menu doesn't work in my Samsung Galaxy On7 as well. I believe Samsung has disabled it.

Comment: Can you confirm if the phone network was working before?I guess the EFS partition is corrupted, you'll need to flash it. Or the phone isn't network unlocked even though it isn't asking for network *code.

Comment: Also, have you tried putting another SIM card?

Comment: yes, it worked before. Yes I have swapped sim and tested

Comment: If you go into settings and advise it to chose the carrier manually, is there any carrier shown to select from and is *not* blocked (i.e. no lock symbol next to it)? Does this SIM you're using work in another device? Just to clarify whether the culprit is the SIM or your device.

Comment: @Izzy When I get into the setting, it will not allow me to search. When I click search it will say mobile network not available. Both automatic and manual search says the same. Yes the sim works fine in another device. I can confirm its definitely device.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the stop sign symbol in Android 5.0 appears whenever your mobile network's service is down/unavailable. (In Stock Android Phones running Android 6.0, the stop icon is associated with Do Not Disturb, however on Samsung Phones with Android 5.0, the stop sign means the network provider's service is down).

One common reason as to why there may be no service is because you are using your phone in a remote area (where service is generally not available)

Now to try and solve the problem, take your phone to your carrier and explain the problem to them (hopefully they will have a solution), or maybe try using a different carrier and see if the problem is solved that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the issue is related to the EFS partition. You need a repair firmware and use Odin to flash it then see if it will solve the problem.

- Try one of these repair firmware: [G530FZXXU1ANL7 / OXX1ANL4 v4.4.4](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24459283995296618)
  or [G530FZXXU1AOB5 / OXE1AOB1 v4.4.4](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24345424848488126)
- Download [Odin](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie2v7DkrbXAhXFOCYKHRftB2gQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fodindownload.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw0xlu5pKsr2KGgcmG30--co) (Windows)
- Download [Samsung USB Drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers) or [Samsung Kies](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyr6eFk7bXAhVEQiYKHWI3DRIQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.samsung.com%2Ffr%2Fkies%2F&usg=AOvVaw2WJtX5n1dq5q-Pu6YvDtNK) (comes with drivers)

Unzip the files, open Odin then load each file in its respective slot. Put the phone in Download Mode, connect to the computer the hit start on Odin.

The operation should fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

dear i think u have to open your mobiles setting,in setting open mobile network and chose 2G.....

Comment: How should that help? If LTE is unavailable, the device will automatically switch to 3G, and then to 2G should 3G be unavailable as well. If there's no signal at all, there's no signal manually either.